# xamarin.forms changing property of observablecollection does not update UI

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have an observrable collection in my class that contains checkboxes. I implemented a button to check all checkboxes at once. I tried just cycling through all elements and checking the box via binding:

```
void selectAll_clicked(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            var x = sender as Button;

            if (!allSelected)
            {
                allSelected = true;
                x.Text = AppResources.DeselectAll;
                foreach (var elem in contactList)
                    elem.isChecked = true;

            }
            else
            {
                allSelected = false;
                x.Text = AppResources.SelectAll;
                foreach (var elem in contactList)
                    elem.isChecked = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

I am sure this effects the list, but the UI isnt updated at all.

How can I make sure the observablecollection "updates" visibly?

I also tried adding propertychanged handler:

```
 private void SetList()
        {
            listview_contacts.ItemsSource = contactList;
            contactList.CollectionChanged += items_CollectionChanged;
        }

        static void items_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.OldItems != null)
            {
                foreach (INotifyPropertyChanged item in e.OldItems)
                    item.PropertyChanged -= item_PropertyChanged;
            }
            if (e.NewItems != null)
            {
                foreach (INotifyPropertyChanged item in e.NewItems)
                    item.PropertyChanged += item_PropertyChanged;
            }
        }

        static void item_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
        }
```

BUt this just says that the cast isnt valid...

Thank you

Comment: an ObservableCollection only notified the UI when items are added or removed.  You need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged on the model class contained within the collection

Comment: well see my question: i said I tried this, but this implemenation just failed. maybe u can tell me why it fails?

Comment: did you implement it on the **model** class?  ie, if you have `ObservableCollection<Widget>` it should be implemented on the `Widget` class

Comment: I had to alter my type. Thank you! :) (see my answer)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achieve that by altering my type like so:

```cs
public class ContactType : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _name;
    private bool _isChecked;

    public string name
    {
        get => _name; set
        {
            _name = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(name)));
        }
    }
    public string phone { get; set; }
    public string initials { get; set; }
    public bool isChecked
    {
        get => _isChecked; set
        {
            _isChecked = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(isChecked)));
        }
    } 

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```